# Getting elements ID after created dynamicly by ajax via JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

in the Name of God
hello.
I have a page that calls another page [answr.php] and it returns some objects like `<input type=number>`.
the problem is that I create those objects with a dynamic name. so I do not know the name of those objects. how can I guess them?
here is a simple code as like as my code:
Page 1:
`I used a part of this function to separate the data in the object's ID.`
`this func is not important and just shows how can I separate my data from an object's ID`

```
<script language="javascript">
function checknumber(theid){
.
.
.
var strObjName = theid.id.toString();
var strDateExt = strObjName.substring(5, 13);
var strIndexExt = strObjName.substring(13, 14);
document.getElementById("testOut").innerHTML = "Object's Name >" + theid.id.toString();
document.getElementById("testOut").innerHTML += "</br> the Date >" + strDateExt;
document.getElementById("testOut").innerHTML += "</br> the Index >" + strIndexExt;
}
```

and this is ans.php that answers over ajax `and creates objects dynamicly`:

```
$strShrtDate=sAddDateNoSlash($strDate,1);//this func returns a date string without slashes like 20161213
$strIdNumber="numId".$strShrtDate."0";
$strOut="<input id=$strIdNumber type='number' onchange = 'checknumber($strIdNumber);'>";
echo $strOut;
echo "<input name='btnSaveTmrow' type='button' value='Save' onClick='fnSaveTmrow();'>";
```

this creates a number object with the name "numId201612130" and a button.
that code creates a HTML tag like this:

```
<input type="number" is="numId201612130" onchange = 'checknumber(numId201612130);'>
<input name='btnSaveTmrow' type='button' value='Save' onClick='fnSaveTmrow();'>
```

numId sayes it is a number input and it's data is for date 2016/12/13 and the special code is 0.
Now I want to get the names like that [ `numId201612130` , `numId201612131` , `numId201612140` , `numId201612141` ,...] for processing some thing and insert into DataBank. how can I do it?
this is my fnSaveTmrow() function is JS:

```
function fnSaveTmrow(){
    url = "SaveTmrow.php";
    var vars = "mID="+i_ID+"&tmrowDate="; // <-- I want to send that data here to send by ajax again after that 'ans.php' code who dynamicly created the number input tag
    fnDoAll(); // this is ajax code
}
```

I want to send the date inserted in the objects IDs and their value Like this:

```
var strObjName = document.getElementById("numId201612130").toString();
var strDateExt = strObjName.substring(5, 13); // contains 20161213
var strIndexExt = strObjName.substring(13, 14); // contains 0
var value = document.getElementById("numId201612130").value;
```

but I do not have `munId201612130` ID because it created dynamicly and  I have to retrive it dynamicly too.
I may have a `function` to returns me those IDs like `munId201612130` or `munId201612141` or `munId201612152`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll` to get a list of every `<input type="number">` that has an `id`.

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=number][id]')
```

Then, call `Array#map` on this list to convert each element to its `id`:

```js
function getAllDynamicIds() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=number][id]')
  return [].map.call(inputs, function (e) {
    return e.id
  })
}

console.log(getAllDynamicIds())
```

```html
<input type="number" id="numId201612130" onchange = 'checknumber(numId201612130);'>
<input type="number" id="numId201612131" onchange = 'checknumber(numId201612131);'>
<input type="number" id="numId201612140" onchange = 'checknumber(numId201612140);'>
<input name='btnSaveTmrow' type='button' value='Save' onClick='fnSaveTmrow();'>
```

Comment: THANKS. this is so good. but it returns this: `numId201612130,numId201612131,numId201612141`. is there any way to put them separately in variables?

Comment: It actually returns an array, which means that you can get each `id` individually using `array[index]`. (`index` begins at zero.)

Comment: thanks a lot. is there any way to relate some objects to a `div` and some others to another `div` and use that **good** search on it like: `myDiv1.numId201612130` or `myDiv2.numId201612172` as here : `var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('div[myDiv1]input[type=number][id]')` @gyre

Comment: If you want to search for inputs within a certain element, you can replace `document` with a reference to that element, e.g. `element.querySelectorAll('input[type=number][id]‌​')` (where `element` could be `document.getElementById('#myDiv1')` or something similar).